# How to detect Android soft-keyboard status/state

Tags: android

How to detect the status of android soft-keyboard programmatically(whether it is hidden or shown).

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: Android has no API for keyboard check. Try sth with boolean and keyback

Comment: I tried ViewTreeObserver() method..
Is there anyother easy way.